# When *exactly* is a function-like macro invocation actually treated as such?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, preprocessor

I'm trying to understand the nitty-gritty details of how the C++ preprocessor works.

Assume we have:

```
#define LP (
#define F(X) a
```

The following code then preprocesses to `a`:

```
#define G1(Y) F Y
G1(LP) 1 )
```

However, the following code preprocesses to `F ( 1 )`:

```
#define G2(Y) F LP
G2(LP) 1 )
```

Okay, so I guess this makes sense if the `LP` argument is already expanded by the time it's fed into the macro.

Except, that's not the case! The following code preprocesses to `F "LP" 1 )`, not `F "(" 1 )`:

```
#define G3(Y) F #Y
G3(LP) 1 )
```

Okay, now I'm confused. What are the rules behind when an open parenthesis is treated as the beginning of a function-like macro invocation?

Comment: Well, the "#" operator specifically says "convert this name to a string literal".  It literally converts `LP` to `"LP"`.  You know, of course, that you shouldn't be doing ANY of this kind of nonsense, right?  Such programs are utterly unmaintainable.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Yes, I know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ preprocessor considers the file to be made of *group-parts*. This rule is defined as follows:

> *group-part*:
>     *control-line*
>     *if-section*
>     *text-lines*
>     `#`*conditionally-supported-directive*
>
> *control-line:*
>     [...]
>     `#` `define` *identifier* *lparen* *identifier-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)` *replacement-list* *new-line*
>     [...]
>
> *lparen:*
>     a `(` character not immediately preceded by whitespace

- [[cpp.pre]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.pre)

This is why `#define Z ()` would not not define a function-like macro, but `#define Z()` would for example.

The preprocessor eliminates separating whitespace when expanding macros, so `F Y` where `Y` expands to `LP )` is treated as `F()`. Expanding function-like macros is described in [[cpp.subst] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.subst#1).

The reason why `F #Y` behaves differently is that [[cpp.subst]](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.subst) exempts `#Y` from macro substitution, and instead, the `#` operator is applied, meaning that

> [...] the original spelling of each preprocessing token in the stringizing argument is retained in the character string literal [...]

- [[cpp.stringize] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.stringize#2)

In your example, `#Y` where `Y` expands to `"LP"`, because `LP` is the original spelling of the argument.

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how critical the intricacies of whitespace handling are here. I *think* I see what's going on now. Thanks!